# Converting EST to GMT shows wrong time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I am trying to convert Newyork time to GMT - it works fine in iPhone, but when I try this in iPad it shows 1 hour+. I am trying to convert 10.00AM to GMT - the currect value is 2.00PM, but I am getting 3.00PM.

Why it is happening?
Here is my code.

```
NSDate *dateTT = datePicker.date;  //10.00PM
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];


NSLog(@"date in gmt---%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:dateTT]);
//date in gmt---3:00 pm
```

Comment: Show us the NSLog of `dateTT`.

Comment: (Whatever problem you have is not in the above code.  An NSDate object stores UTC/GMT internally, so if it's wrong it was set wrong to begin with.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup the date picker correctly? Setting up the date picker using:

```
NSTimeZone *est = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
datePicker.timeZone = est;
datePicker.dateValue = [NSDate new];
```

and placing your code in the `IBAction` method for the picker produces 2pm as you expect (10pm EDT goes to 2pm GMT).

Comment: @soorejbabu - It's works in conjunction with the OP's code as stated, but whether it solved the problem the OP had we don't know as they never accepted the answer (they never accepted answers to any of the questions they asked, so lack of acceptance tells us nothing). If you have a similar problem then try this solution, if it doesn't solve your issue ask your own question and someone may help.